# How to allow users to embed YouTube & Vimeo videos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, vimeo

How can I go about allowing users to embed YouTube and Vimeo videos in my Rails app?

1. I'd provide a text field or text area where users can add the link of the video they wish to embed.
2. Click add and have my app show a spinner while the details are being gathered.
3. When the details are found, I'd want them displayed on the page before user can finally submit the post.

I'm guessing the HTML, link details will need to be stored in the database so the video can automatically be displayed every time the page is visited.

HTML5 has a file API that gives me the ability to display users local file data on the fly. Wondering if there is something similar for display remote data or would normal ajax be used?

Is there a standard way of doing this? Also are there any tutorials out there on how to do this in rails? Would like to go about doing this in the most safest and securest way.

I love tutorials and screencasts so I'd really be thankful for info on where I can find one to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use open graph protocol to fetch site information before user sending the form.

I suggest the following gem:

https://github.com/intridea/opengraph

Open graph protocol:

http://ogp.me/

And I guess you should store all the fetched information in database.

Comment: Just read through ogp.me website and that is some good info. I've always wondered if something like that ogp was available. This should make things easy for me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Video Thumb gem](https://github.com/tgezginis/video_thumb) is probably what you are looking for.

It handles vimeo, youtube and potentially others.

Then you just do:

```
<%= VideoPlayer::player(library_item.url, 700, 420).html_safe %>
```

In your view to display an automatically generated embed code.